# aegir nginx logging

Tags: php, nginx, logging

I'm a developer rather than a sysadmin by trade. I'm working on a drupal site that's been installed with aegir which is clearly dying part-way through loading several drupal pages.

I reckon there's a PHP fatal error which is killing processing.

However, I can't seem to get errors either logging or displaying. I've configured the /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini to set log_errors = On, with error level set to E_ALL and pointing to a valid logfile.

Is there anything else I could have missed in either the nginx.conf or the php.ini? Am I even using the right php.ini? (there are 5 on the system)

My other suspicion is that maybe there are two different web services running, one to provide Aegir and one to provide the hosted Drupal sites.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you enabled Nginx Log to debug mode . Please check below link /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is the file in which you have to make changes http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html

Comment: Nginx debug log has nothing to do with **php**.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61045 in php-fpm with error handling.